# Trying to create attributes from a functions return statement

Tags: python, django, django-models

I think I'm lacking understanding of scope. In my "Store" model I have a function to take the `address` field and turn it into latitude and longitude. I want to take the two values I return and use them to create `latitude` and `longitude` attributes for my "Store" model. My goal is to use them in my template like `{{store.latitude}}` and `{{store.longitude}}`

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_coords(self):
        geolocator = Nominatim()
        location = geolocator.geocode(self.address)
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        return latitude, longitude

    latitude = ...
    longitude = ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Store"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**new model**

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Store"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def update_coordinates(self):
        geolocator = Nominatim()
        location = geolocator.geocode(self.address)
        self.latitude = location.latitude
        self.longitude = location.longitude
        self.save(update_fields=["latitude", "longitude"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `models.py` with this code block. Then you can pass store instance to template. You may return the values and pass them to template statically but this will be safer to use future because this updates database when save method called.

```py
    class Store(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        latitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        longitude = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Stores"

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

        def update_coordinates(self):
            geolocator = Nominatim()
            location = geolocator.geocode(self.address)
            self.latitude = location.latitude
            self.longitude = location.longitude
            self.save(update_fields=["latitude", "longitude"])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for however I cant seem to call it in my template. Other fields are working like `{{store.name}}` but `{{store.latitude}}` and `{{store.longitude}}` don't render anything

Comment: `latitude` and `longitude` are model fields, right? Just print `store.__dict__` and update your question with the output to see what is in there. You should print that before you pass the store instance to template from `views.py`

Comment: Turns out I forgot to add CharFields for latitude and longitude. They render in the template now however when I save a Store object its not updating the oneoff values of "1" I entered.

Comment: I am a little confused. Can you share a code block in your question that is not working as expected? If you have model fields and migrated the fields to database, they should update when you save `Store` instance.